# set Image visible/hidden in div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I implmented some code from diffrent post on here the code works in js fiddle but not locally any help is greatly appreciated

I know there are paragrapgh and not images below but this is just for testing first

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>DY Fitness</title>
         <script src="imagesel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <img id="imga" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" />
        <img id="imgb" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" />
        <img id="imgc" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" />
        <div id="show" style=" visibility:hidden;">
          <p id="showa">AAA</p>
          <p id="showb">BBB</p>
          <p id="showc">CCC</p>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS code imagesel.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#imga').click(function() {
  $('#showa').css('visibility', ($('#showa').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
  $('#showb').css('visibility', ($('#showb').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'hidden');
  $('#showc').css('visibility', ($('#showc').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'hidden');
})
 $('#imgb').click(function() {
    $('#showb').css('visibility', ($('#showb').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
    $('#showa').css('visibility', ($('#showa').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'hidden');
    $('#showc').css('visibility', ($('#showc').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'hidden');
 })
  $('#imgc').click(function() {
    $('#showc').css('visibility', ($('#showc').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
    $('#showb').css('visibility', ($('#showb').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'hidden');
    $('#showa').css('visibility', ($('#showa').css('visibility') == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: you did not included the jQuery library

Comment: Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>` before `</body>` or in `<head>` of your document and your script should work. Also, your script can be written in 3 lines of jQuery but that's not any more the scope of the question.

Comment: I added <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> just befor </body> but still no look this is strange ? the Code seems good to me not sure what im missing

Comment: why would you remove `https://` ?

Comment: I didnt that just the bit i copied to paste here https:// is there also

Comment: i fixed it by calling jquery before the js file thanks for the help Roko C. Buljan

Comment: Lol! Exactly @RokoC.Buljan Just 3 lines of jquery code. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/vL11q421/2/

Comment: Thats deadly didnt know it could be done like that thanks

Comment: @AkshayaRaghuvanshi :) no, I really meant 3! http://jsbin.com/yumiqu/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments your problem is most likely that you didn't load the jquery library. But that is a horrible way to do what you are trying to do. It could be done much more simply like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>DY Fitness</title>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
         <script src="imagesel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- note that I added 'data-show' attributes with the id of the element to show -->
        <img id="imga" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" data-show="showa" />
        <img id="imgb" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" data-show="showb" />
        <img id="imgc" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" data-show="showc" />
        <div id="show" style="visibility:hidden;">
          <p id="showa">AAA</p>
          <p id="showb">BBB</p>
          <p id="showc">CCC</p>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then your javascript would look like this:

```
$(function(){
     $('img').click(function(){ // when an image is clicked
        var id = $(this).data('show'); // get the value of the data-show attribute
        $('#show > p').css('visibility', 'hidden'); // hide all of the p inside #show
        $('#' + id).css('visibility', 'visible'); // display the specific p
        $('#show').css('visibility', 'visible'); // show the div holding your p items.
    });
});
```

Using data attributes is a great way to pass data to click handlers.

Comment: Thanks ill check them out in the future but i solved the above problem jQuery was the issue thanks for the answear though

Comment: You know, I'm going to file a complaint with SO. You should not be allowed to downvote without explaining yourself. I don't know who downvoted my answer or @Roko C. Buljan's  answer. Both are valid. If you don't have the guts to explain your reason for downvoting then get out of SO! Some of us are actually trying to help here.

Comment: @GreggDuncan don't file complaints... it's the way it is an the downvoter is unknown even to the SO gurus. For the exact reason not to convert SO into a revenge playground. Time will tell, people will come and upvote good answers, sometimes even the Downvoter who rather stayed anonymous might come back and remove the downvote after seeing edits and improvements on answers.

Comment: I understand it's just my humble opinion that SO should not allow a downvote without a comment. even if they allow the comment to be anonymous that would be OK. but at least force them to form a coherent sentence or 2 explaining themselves. This is just the 3rd time today for me. And it's aggravating. I have the feeling someone may be targeting me for downvoting their answer and I took the time to explain why.

Comment: @GreggDuncan that's actually an almost clever idea. I thought about **Anonymous comments** even before you commented it. The problem is I think that even if you suggest this on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), admins and community will be concerned about the average loss of downvotes (which in the majority of the time are really useful to sort good/bad answers up/down) cause of the *ease* of upvoting and the *time-lossy* downvote process. So I even think that's the reason still today we don't have anonymous-comments on downvotes.

Comment: now thinking about it, a much better approach: since downvoters gets -1 rep points, would be nice to see a -0 loss of rep if you provide a useful comment... Just thinking aloud.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working cause **you're missing jQuery**

Add jQuery and volia http://jsbin.com/yumiqu/edit?html,css,js,output

By just adding a class `.invisible` to your CSS:

```
.invisible{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

and assigning that class to your child elements instead:

```
<img id="imga" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" />
<img id="imgb" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" />
<img id="imgc" src="http://www.placekitten.com/100/100" />
<div id="show">
  <p class="invisible" id="showa">AAA</p>
  <p class="invisible" id="showb">BBB</p>
  <p class="invisible" id="showc">CCC</p>
</div>
```

this is all you need (wrapped in DOm ready ofc):
http://jsbin.com/yumiqu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
$('[id^=img]').click(function() {
  var $target = $("#show"+ this.id.split("img")[1]);    // $(#show+ a, b, c...)
  $("[id^=show]").not( $target ).addClass("invisible"); // Remove from all
  $target.toggleClass("invisible");                     // add to target el.
});
```

Comment: I fixed the problem thanks for youre help apprecite it

Comment: @Roko, Someone downvoted your answer for some reason. But didn't have the guts to comment on their issue with your answer. I upvoted you to at least get you back to even.

Comment: @GreggDuncan thx for the fair play! same magic happened to you :) nice example